# Why does moment-timezone display incorrect GMT offset for some timestamps in same timezone?

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I'm using `moment-timezone` 0.5.1 on node 6.3.0
I'm primarily dealing with the Hong Kong timezone, which has been using `GMT+0800` [since 1904](http://www.hko.gov.hk/gts/time/History_of_HK_Time_Service.htm).
Before that, it was using `GMT+0736` [since 1885](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Time)

Yet for some reason, `moment-timezone` formats some dates near the epoch to display `GMT+0900`, which doesn't seem to have any basis in history.

I can't seem to find the pattern nor can I reproduce this issue in more recent timestamps.

**After epoch**

```
moment.tz(123456780, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Fri Jan 02 1970 18:17:36 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(1234567800, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Thu Jan 15 1970 14:56:07 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(5999999999, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Wed Mar 11 1970 18:39:59 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(9000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Wed Apr 15 1970 12:00:00 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(9300000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sat Apr 18 1970 23:20:00 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(12345678000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sun May 24 1970 06:21:18 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(9999999999, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Mon Apr 27 1970 02:46:39 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(9900000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sat Apr 25 1970 23:00:00 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(9500000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Tue Apr 21 1970 07:53:20 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(9400000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Mon Apr 20 1970 04:06:40 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(9400000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Mon Apr 20 1970 04:06:40 GMT+0900'
```

**Before epoch**

```
moment.tz(-9000000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Thu Oct 19 1684 15:36:42 GMT+0736'
moment.tz(-90000000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sun Jan 06 -0882 15:36:42 GMT+0736'
moment.tz(-500000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sat Feb 27 1954 07:06:40 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(-100000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Mon Oct 31 1966 22:13:20 GMT+0800'
moment.tz(-900000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Wed Jun 25 1941 17:00:00 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(-200000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sat Aug 31 1963 13:26:40 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(-800000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Sat Aug 26 1944 02:46:40 GMT+0900'
moment.tz(-900000000000, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString() // 'Wed Jun 25 1941 17:00:00 GMT+0900'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's also a historical answer, based on Hong Kong's adoption of Daylight Savings Time:

> Hong Kong adopted daylight saving measures in 1941. However, in the 1970s, the government found these measures unnecessary as Hong Kong is at a relatively low latitude. The practice was eliminated in 1979.

Taking a quick look at the difference between 1941 and 1942, that seems like where you see the switch between GMT+8 and GMT+9:

```
moment.tz(new Date('1/1/1941'), 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString()
// 'Wed Jan 01 1941 16:00:00 GMT+0800'

moment.tz(new Date('1/1/1942'), 'Asia/Hong_Kong').toString()
// 'Thu Jan 01 1942 17:00:00 GMT+0900'
```